# Change recursive vector to atomic vector for t-test

Tags: r

I'm new to R and am trying to run a t-test for two means. I keep getting the error is.atomic is not TRUE. I know I need to make my data atomic, but I haven't found a way online.

I've ran code to check that the data is recursive and did a as.data.frame(mydata).

```
titanic_summary <- data.frame(Outcome = c("Survived", "Died"), 
             Mean_Age = c(28.34369, 30.62618),
             N = c(342, 549),
             Total_Missing = c(52, 125))
titanic_summary
```

## Run a stats test (two sample T-test)

```
str(titanic_summary)

as.data.frame(titanic_summary)
is.atomic(titanic_summary)
is.recursive(titanic_summary)

titanic_test <- titanic_summary %>%
  t.test(Outcome~Mean_Age)
```

Error in var(x) : is.atomic(x) is not TRUE

Comment: You have one observation per every outcome, what exactly do you want to test?

Answer (score 2):

`t.test` does not work the way you seem to think. To avoid that particular error, you could instead use something like `titanic_test <- t.test(Mean_Age ~ Outcome, data = titanic_summary)` but that would just give you different errors, which comes down to the real question:

You presumably want to see whether there may be a relationship between age and survival, i.e. whether the difference in average ages of `2.28249` is significant but you will need the individual ages or some other additional information about dispersion for this

If you do use the detailed dataset then I suspect that what you really want is something like this:

```
library(titanic)
titanic_test <- t.test(Age ~ Survived, data = titanic_train)
```

which would give (for the Kaggle selected training set used in the `titanic` package)

```
> titanic_test

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  Age by Survived
t = 2.046, df = 598.84, p-value = 0.04119
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.09158472 4.47339446
sample estimates:
mean in group 0 mean in group 1 
       30.62618        28.34369
```